# Cannot find element on the selected frame

Tags: python, html, robotframework

I am trying to get an link from another frame on our webpage. After using

`Select Frame    css=frame[name'submenu']
Click Link    css=#navigation_user > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)`

I would have directly used the `link=users` BUT there is another link with the same link and it is a parent element of it so I can't use it.

Any ideas on how can I access this link?
Excerpt of the html:

    `<frame src="sample.asp" name="submenu">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="navigation">
                    <a href="Users.asp?null=" target="main"></a>
                    <a class="navigationheadline">
                        <span id="user" class="navigationheadline">Users</span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="navigation_user">
            <tr>
                <td class="navigation">
                    <a href="UserSearch.asp?null=" target="main">
                        <span class="navigation" onclick="hideNv()">Users</span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </frame>`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so what is the problem?  That link exists with that locator when you're on the web page but the test isn't finding it?  The locator is pretty nasty, so I'd suggest you get an id added to what you want to access for ease of use.  If the locator is there when you access the page manually, yet isn't there in the test, it sounds like a timing issue.

Comment: the problem is that it can't find the element (`<span class="navigation" onclick="hideNv()">Users</span>`) even when i switched frames. this is not a timing issue as the element shows everytime.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a different locator method? like xpath or jquery?  I think the route of your problem is the locator you're using.  How did you determine the one you're using is correct?  Just plucked out of dev tools?

```
xpath=//*[@id="navigation_user"]/tr/td/a/span
```

Comment: Haven't tried it. I do my own css selectors not just get it via get unique selector. I'll update once I do though